# I am trying to compare 2 sets of matched groups in regex python

Tags: python-3.x, regex-group

The files are the exact same, I'm applying regex to string input on copies of 2 exact same file, but i am not sure how to do the comparison of the groups. Here is my code:

```
for res1 in result1:
            for res2 in result2:
                res2 = res2.group()
            if res1.group() != res2:
                print(res1.group())
```

trying to compare it like this only the last group matches, so I believe it has something to do with indentation. result1 is the regex result on the first file, result 2 is the regex result on second file. they're callable objects, so I'm looping through them and tryin to compare. There should be no difference. Would anyone have any tips? I am thinking about using  isdiff  instead, although I have never used it. Below is a bit more of the code.

```
else:
    read1 = open(fle + '.txt')
    result1 = re.finditer(regex, read1.read())

    
    with open(infile, "r") as x:
        result2 = re.finditer(regex, x.read())
        
        for res1 in result1:
            for res2 in result2:
                res2 = res2.group()
            if res1.group() != res2:
```

everything else in the script seems to be working as intended, at this point I am stuck comparing regex groupings, which in the current situation should be the same. I've recopied the file a few times and tested.

Comment: You really should add sample data to your question.

Answer (score 0):

As you have mentioned, the problem lies in indentation of the for-loop:

```py
for res1 in result1:
  for res2 in result2:
    res2 = res2.group()
  if res1.group() != res2:
    print(res1.group())
```

What happens is that the inner-loop keeps overwriting the `res2` variable until the loop finishes. At this point, the value of `res2` is the group of the last match of `regex`. This, in turn, causes the comparison to check only the last match of `res2`, for each `res` match.

You can easily see this behavior in the loop below:

```py
>>> for number in [1, 2, 3]:
...   number *= 2
... print(number)

6
```

In order for the comparison to check all pairs of results, move it inside the inner loop:

```py
for res1 in result1:
  for res2 in result2:
    res2 = res2.group()
    if res1.group() != res2:
      print(res1.group())
```